# Pesquisar id retornado do json_encode() dentro do mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho o seguinte conteúdo no campo `pro_are_id` : `["11","3"]` este conteúdo fiz com `json_encode()`, gostaria de efetuar uma consulta ao banco de dados e saber se existe este `id` em específico ou não, tentei dessa forma:

```
$area = 1;
$this->db->like("pro_are_id", $area);
return $this->db->get('produto')->result();
```

O problema com este método é que ele irá retornar true, porque existe o 11, que contém o número 1 (id que estou pesquisando).

**Qual seria a maneira correta de obter o resultado? Sendo que não posso usar simplesmente o WHERE?**

Obs: Estou usando o codeigniter, mas se a resposta for em PHP, consigo utilizar dentro das diretrizes do CI.

Comment: E se você buscar pela string ao invés de buscar pelo inteiro? Tipo `$area = '"1"'`, buscando pelo valor `"1"` ao invés de `1`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Não daria certo, quando eu faço o retorno da query, ele usa %1%, ou seja, ele vai trazer este resultado, preciso de uma forma que retorne apenas o 1, sem usar os %.

Comment: Como você está retorno o valor do json_encode? Porque daí você pode recuperar `$area->pro_are_id`

Comment: já pensou em primeiro retornar a consulta sem o like o resultado dela usar o array_search? http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui a solução da seguinte forma:

```
$area = 1;
$this->db->like("pro_are_id", json_encode($area));
return $this->db->get('produto')->result();
```

Passando o json_encode() pela $area, me retorna só se tiver o registro... Não parece certo, mas aqui funcionou perfeitamente. A não ser que há uma outra lógica que funcione melhor.

Comment: se o campo "pro_are_id" for numero o ideal é usar o get_where para gerar a query com `where pro_are_id = x` e não `where pro_are_id like "5"`. para eficiência é mais rápido o = que o like.

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que vi da documentação, tenta usar:

```
$this->db->get_where('produto', array('pro_are_id', 1))->result();
```

Não sendo precido `$this->db->like("pro_are_id", $area);`